# CreateObject OnTick

Tags: mql5

I managed to put some objects on the strategy tester Chart as follows:

```
void OnTick() {

ObjectCreate(0,"test9999",OBJ_ARROW_LEFT_PRICE,0,TimeCurrent(),SymbolInfoDouble(_Symbol,SYMBOL_BID)-0,03);
ObjectCreate(0,"test9991",OBJ_ARROW_RIGHT_PRICE,0,TimeCurrent(),SymbolInfoDouble(_Symbol,SYMBOL_BID)-0,03);
ObjectCreate(0,"test9992",OBJ_ARROW_SELL,0,TimeCurrent(),SymbolInfoDouble(_Symbol,SYMBOL_BID)+0,1);
ObjectCreate(0,"test9993",OBJ_VLINE,0,TimeCurrent(),SymbolInfoDouble(_Symbol,SYMBOL_BID)+0,1);

Print(TimeCurrent());
Print(SymbolInfoDouble(_Symbol,SYMBOL_BID));

}
```

However, the created objects do not move with current time and bid price. As can be seen, I also print the current time and bid price and when I start the backtest I see that both, the current time and the bid price change in the print out. Any ideas why the objects are not moving with current time and bid price?

Answer (score 2):

`ObjectCreate()` returns `TRUE` of `FALSE`.True only if it is possible to create a new object, then the object is drawn and its properties are set as in parameters. If it is impossible to create a new object(in case if its name is not allowed, object already exists etc), it returns false.

I think you should create the objects in `OnInit()`, and change `OBJPROP_TIME1 and OBJPROP_PRICE1` in `OnTick()` function. Or control that objects exist in some other way with boolean parameters.

Use `ObjectSetInteger(0,"test9999",OBJPROP_TIME1,TimeCurrent());` to move its time parameter, but keep in mind that it doesnt make much sence to update each tick, at least this does not lead to moving the object, once per bar is enough.
`ObjectSetDouble(0,"test9999",OBJPROP_PRICE1,Bid-0.03);` - for moving the object along the price scale.

If you have `OBJ_HLINE` - its parameter `OBJPROP_TIME1` doesn't make much sence, only price matters. If you have an object that have two price or time parameters, e.g., `OBJ_TREND` (trend line) - update both `OBJPROP_PRICE1 & OBJPROP_PRICE2`